# Django - Allow User to Edit Profile and then Show Updated Profile fields

Tags: django-forms

I have the form populating with the user profile information, but when I click save, it doesn't actually update.

Any clues/hints as to which part I need to modify is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

views.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    user = request.user
    form = EditProfileForm(initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name})
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)

def edit_profile(request):

    user = request.user
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():


            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']

            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s'%(reverse('profile')))

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "edit_profile.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name') 

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

edit_profile.html

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Edit Profile</h1>


<form method="POST" action="/accounts/profile/" class="" />
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^register/$', 'accounts.views.registration_view', name='auth_register'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'accounts.views.login_view', name='auth_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'accounts.views.logout_view', name='auth_logout'),
    url(r'^profile/$', 'accounts.views.profile_view', name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', 'accounts.views.edit_profile', name='edit_profile'),
]
```

Comment: I think I know what it is, but I'll need to see your `urls.py` file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action in your form is `POST`ing to `profile_view` and not `edit_profile` and your forms are self closing so they aren't being `POST`ed correctly.

Change this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/accounts/profile/" class="" />
```

To this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/accounts/profile/edit" class="" >
```

Or even better, use the [django url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'edit_profile' %}" class="" >
```